# Numerical integration of a function with several variables

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I need to calculate the next integral

$$ F_l(R)=\int_0^{\infty} {dk k^2j_l(k R)*2*\exp[-0.36k^2](k)\rho_l(k)(18/k^2)P_l(\cos{\beta})}$$

where ρl(k) is given by

$$ \rho_l(k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{dr r^2 j_l(k r)\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}{2\pi\rho(r,\theta)Y_{l0}(\theta)\sin{\theta}d\theta}\right)}$$

At the same time ρ(r,θ) is given by

$$\rho(r,\theta)=\rho_0/(1+\exp[(r-1.07Ad^{1/3}[1+b_2Y_{20}(\theta)+b_4Y_{40}(\theta)])/0.54]$$

In order to calculate this integral I put everything in a single function and then integrate all variables θ, r and k for given value of l. In all next equations Ad=178, Zd=80, b2=-0.113 and b4=-0.026; we have

```
Rd[th_, Ad_, b2_, b4_] := 1.07 Ad^(1/3)(1 + b2*SphericalHarmonicY[2,0, 
th,0]+b4*SphericalHarmonicY[4, 0, th, 0])
```

and then the function

```
fd[r_, th_, Ad_, b2_, b4_] := 1/(1 + Exp[(r - Rd[th, Ad, b2, b4])/0.54])
```

The function Ddcd[r, Ad, Zd, th, b2, b4] (which is ρ(r,θ))  is given by

```
Ddcd[r_, th_, Ad_, Zd_, b2_, b4_] :=   Zd/(NIntegrate[      2 Pi*rr^2*fd[rr, 
tth, Ad, b2, b4]*Sin[tth], {rr, 0,        Infinity}, {tth, 0, Pi},       
Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}])*   fd[r, th, Ad, b2, b4]
```

The integrand of Fl(R) is

```
fcd[R_, k_, r_, th_, Ad_, Zd_, b2_, b4_, l_] :=      
k^2*SphericalBesselJ[l, k R]*(2*Exp[-0.36^2])*
(18/k^2)*(2 Pi*r^2*SphericalBesselJ[l, k r]*
Ddcd[r, Ad, Zd, th, b2, b4])*SphericalHarmonicY[l, 0, th, 0]*
Sin[th]
```

The integral I am trying to calculate is given by the code

```
FR0[R_, Ad_, Zd_, b2_, b4_, l_] = 
Interpolation[
Table[{R, 
NIntegrate[
fcd[R, k, r, th ,Ad ,Zd ,b2 ,b4 ,l], {k, 0, Infinity}, {r, 0, Infinity}, {th, 
 0, Pi}, Method -> 
{Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 
2]}, {R, 0.01, 40, 0.1}]] 
[R]
```

My problem is the integrals for l=0,2,4 are taking a lot of time (hours). How can I make the calculations faster ? Is there anyway to modify the integral so the calculations are faster ?Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried Monte-Carlo methods? `Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^6}`. Also it would be helpful if you could write your constants and functions in a top-down order, and I'm getting an error _Raw object ... cannot be used as an iterator_

Comment: In `Ddcd` you're integrating with respect to `r`, but you've passed in `r` as an argument. Which means `r` is getting replaced by a value and I get the message _Raw object 178 cannot be used as an iterator._ The same happens with `th`. If you replace these variables with different names from the arguments it fixes it: `Ddcd[r_, th_, Ad_, Zd_, b2_, b4_] := 
 Zd/(NIntegrate[
     2 Pi*rr^2*fd[rr, tth, Ad, b2, b4]*Sin[tth], {rr, 0, 
      Infinity}, {tth, 0, Pi}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}])*
  fd[r, th, Ad, b2, b4]`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I do not have that mistake because my code is slightly different; the integral part is another function. I did not write it here because I thought it would be too long. Thank you again